# gcloud comman line redirect to standard output

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform, stdout, gcloud, stderr

Let's say I have a simple bash script as the one provided below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

exec 19>&1
export BASH_XTRACEFD=19
set -xe -o pipefail

echo "Test message"
#python /python_script.py --name ${NAME} --city ${CITY}

gcloud config set project ${PROJECT_NAME}
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=${GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS}
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=${FAKE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS}
```

My objective is to log the first two `gcloud` invocations to stdout. There seems to be no way of doing this in the official docs (https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference). I suspect that all `gcloud` output is logged to stderr. The result of the third `gcloud` invocation (that is where a real error happens) should be redirected to stderr.

If I execute

```
/script.sh 1>/stdout_text.txt 2>/stderr_text.txt
```

I want to see in the `stdout_text.txt` file content like:

```
...
Updated property [core/project].
Activated service account credentials for: [service-account-123@my-company-ci.iam.gserviceaccount.com]
...
```

and in the `stderr_text.txt` file content like this:

```
...
ERROR: gcloud crashed (Error): Incorrect padding

If you would like to report this issue, please run the following command:
  gcloud feedback

To check gcloud for common problems, please run the following command:
  gcloud info --run-diagnostics
...
```

The current situation is that all the output that `gcloud` produces is redirected to `stderr`. Can I change `gcloud`'s behaviour so that diagnostics/non-error events go to `stdout` and real errors go to `stderr`?

Comment: And, what are you seeing for now?

Comment: Thanks, I updated the description (the last paragraph).

Comment: I reproduced it and I didn't find a trick to solve that!!

Comment: This is not possible to be done with gcloud, what you could do is open a Feature Request in [Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187143&template=0) so that the product team can consider implementing an optional functionality for types of outputs in gcloud.

Comment: no idea why they would put it in `stderr`...